# Replacement supports, removing old partial walls

Tags: walls, structural, beam, building

My old kitchen used to be divided into two rooms with a wall separating the rooms.
At some point, most of wall was removed, however, they kept some portions extending out.

east wall - extension comes out 6.5"

west wall - extension comes out 21.5"

ceiling - extension comes down 9"

width of extensions: 5"

We removed some drywall on the extensions to find a newish horizontal beam supported by 2 newish vertical posts. Within west extension there is also gas pipe, condensation pipe, and conduit running vertically - these are between the west vertical post and west side wall.

PHOTOS https://photos.app.goo.gl/RmgfkaA8cPy2sxgU6

Goal: to either remove extensions entirely or at least reduce depth so they don't stick out so far from side walls, while minimizing the amount of destruction.

My carpenter wants to add new horizonal beam above the ceiling going into side walls & 2 new support posts inside west & east walls. He would also move pipes into west wall.

But I'm wondering if there is another option that would be less work. I'm not a builder so I'm no expert but my idea is:

-running new horizontal beam full width across into west and east walls.

-This new beam would run parallel to the existing old beam.

-In the side walls, this new beam would be supported by new posts.

-At that point, we can remove the old horizontal beam & vertical posts.

-The existing vertical pipes would not get moved but more effectively "bundled" and pushed closer to west wall.

-I would still need to have an extension of maybe 8" coming out of west wall & there would be the new horizontal beam replacing old horizontal beam. At least the east extension goes away.

Is this idea "significantly" easier, less risky, less expensive?

Comment: going from just your description it's impossible to tell.

Comment: a link to photo album is included above

Comment: yep, im coming to that realization...well, time to put drywall back on.... now i know definitively what's in there